# How complex a program can be without variables?

Tags: variables

Theoretically, is it possible to write programs without using variables? What will the most complex program look like? Does the answer vary depending on the language? 
Would you be able to use functions? Control flow?

Comment: How do you define a variable? For example if you assign a variable only once, is it really a variable? And what about function parameters? Those are a kind of local variable in many languages. You can use them together with tail call recursion to emulate ordinary local variables.

Comment: @CodesInChaos those are great questions which I didn't think about:  probably my question wasn't clear enough. My background is Python, so my current mental model of variable is a label for primitives and a reference for non-primitives and a variable can be mutated.

Comment: If you're using Python you're going to have trouble with those damn global variables.  `python -c "print(dir())"` proves that even the simplest Python program (ie. a zero byte excluding shebang implementation of /bin/true), is too complex to not have any variables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A language doesn't need variables to be Turing-complete; therefore, *every* program that can be written *at all*, can also be written without variables.

Some notable languages which don't have variables, yet are Turing-complete, are:

- [Universal Turing Machines](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine)
- [SK(I) Combinator Calculus](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus)
- [brainfuck](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck)
- [Unlambda](http://www.madore.org/~david/programs/unlambda/)
- [Forth](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language))
- [Iota](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota), [Jot](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Jot), [Zot](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Zot)

Also related is the concept of [Tacit Programming](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming) and writing code in [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree).

In general, by thinking about how data flows through a system and is transformed and reduced in the process instead of mutating state, you can get rid of variables, and express computation as a series of combinations of functions. Think of a Unix shell pipeline, for example.

But the really obvious example is: your computer. It doesn't have variables, yet it executes all your programs.

Comment: This answer saves this question. I didn't know this was even possible.

Comment: As a generalization, a stack machine doesn't need to refer to its data as "variables", even though most operations (non-commutative) would have to distinguish between, say, subtrahend versus minuend.

Comment: @rwong: Most pure stack machines (hardware) don't have variables at all - they have parameters (function arguments). In most programming languages they are very different things though most programmers tend to mix them up because they feel like the same thing.

Comment: @rwong: Thanks. Your comment led me to realize that I missed the most obvious example of all: my computer! It has registers, it has RAM, it has cache, it has a CPU (several of them in fact), but you know what it *doesn't* have? *Named* state, i.e. variables.

Comment: A "variable" isn't something with the name "variable", it is something that uses the _semantic context_ of a variable. A register that is being used to store a counter or even a specific spot on a turing machine's tape being used to store temp values while doing it's processing may not have _the name_ variable, but they are pretty much acting like those. Same goes for memory addresses - using a memory space to store something _is_ using a variable, even if you do it by hand, as you would do with brainfuck. Variables are mental models, not "physical things".

Comment: In other words - every single cell on the tape of a Turing Machine is a variable that can be read or written to. So, no, none of those examples you provided are actually "without variables".

Comment: @TSar The word "variable" has many meanings. Variables as a feature of a programming language mimicks the general mathematical idea of variables and specifically hides needless references to memory addresses, offsets and registers. It's possible to write complex programs without variables as a concept of the programming language but I'd argue it's not possible to write them without using the mathematical idea of variables.

Comment: 1) Brainfuck has a Data Pointer that is a variable. 2) Unlambda has some hoop jumps but ends up using $x as a variable in the end. 3) SKI is not a programming language. 4) Forth has _Words_, that are pretty much variables.

Comment: @COMEFROM Any Turing-Complete language is dependent on variables, on any form it may appear. The Turing Machine itself is defined as a set of operations over a tape with cells that can hold symbols. Any given cell is a variable. The mathematical concept of a variable is a intrinsic part of any turing machine!